# custom converter in jwt oauth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I try to implement oauth2 authorisation_code flow with Spring boot and Keycloak.
My Spring boot application acts as a client and a resource server, and
Keycloak is the authorization provider.
I make a request of the resource through the browser, then Keycloak's login page shows up, I enter the credentials of my user and I get the resource.
What I wanna do, is retrieving the resource role-based.
So, I have created a custom converter to add the role values (adding prefix ROLE_) that I want into Grant Authorities.
The problem is my converter seems to never been called, resulting to an 403 response

SecurityConfig.java

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    private final JwtAuthConverter jwtAuthConverter;
    
    @Value(value = "${jwt.auth.converter.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuerUri;
    
    
    @Bean   
    public SecurityFilterChain clientFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {  
        return http.authorizeHttpRequests(req-> req
                 .anyRequest()
                .authenticated())
        .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer -> oauth2ResourceServer
                .jwt(jwt -> 
                        // here I set my custom converter, but it's never called
                    jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthConverter)         
                )
         )
        .build();
     }
        
 
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withIssuerLocation(issuerUri).build();
    } 
}
```

application.yml

```
jwt:
  auth:
    converter:
      resource-id: john-rest-api
      principal-attribute: preferred_username
      issuer-uri: http://localhost:8180/realms/john
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          john-rest-api:
            client-id: john-rest-api
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/john-rest-api
            scope: openid, profile, roles
        provider:
           john-rest-api:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8180/realms/john
        resourceserver:
          jwt:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8180/realms/john
            jwk-set-uri: ${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

JwtAuthConverter.java (my custom converter)

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthConverter implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken>{
    
    private final JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter =
            new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    
    @Value(value = "${jwt.auth.converter.principal-attribute}")
    private String principalAttribute;
    
    @Value(value = "${jwt.auth.converter.resource-id}")
    private String resourceId;

    @Override
    public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(Jwt jwt) {
              // ...
              // never been here !!!
              // code to add roles that i want to grant authorities, adding to them the prefix "ROLE_"
        }
}
```

DemoController.java

```
@GetMapping("/hello-2")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('client_admin')")    
public String hello() { 
  return "hello";
```

Any ideas on this will be really helpful. Also, if there is a tutorial on how to implement authorization_code flow with Keycloak and Spring boot (I couldn't find any), will be helpful too.

LOGS

```
2023-11-06T14:38:22.468+02:00 DEBUG 7100 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login/oauth2/code/john-rest-api?state=482b447Sm8xpm__xVJzRgLzLIaEl1CwUBi79b7C2MZ8%3D&session_state=06bb0831-88be-4580-8717-e08985098f2c&code=c4800a89-9de1-4f6e-8c80-f74b30825286.06bb0831-88be-4580-8717-e08985098f2c.06b90e8a-c3a3-40fe-877a-41d5f3131066
2023-11-06T14:38:22.666+02:00 DEBUG 7100 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .s.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy : Changed session id from F4F280CA99D66DCFD5C20757B8D61BEA
2023-11-06T14:38:22.667+02:00 DEBUG 7100 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [f865bdf4-8438-4ac5-a587-917ed06fb82e], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=hdODzgXtXVwmIIC8I0_-Lg, sub=f865bdf4-8438-4ac5-a587-917ed06fb82e, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/realms/john, typ=ID, preferred_username=john, given_name=, nonce=BoS9yhBYY4d-aY0yHdbX-3IK_LF6uBl3uFEQ1vp6L6c, sid=06bb0831-88be-4580-8717-e08985098f2c, aud=[john-rest-api], acr=1, azp=john-rest-api, auth_time=2023-11-06T12:38:22Z, exp=2023-11-06T12:43:22Z, session_state=06bb0831-88be-4580-8717-e08985098f2c, family_name=, iat=2023-11-06T12:38:22Z, jti=3951b6f2-fda1-4374-8e81-556881d7c9a6}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=F4F280CA99D66DCFD5C20757B8D61BEA], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@4f0bbf2a]
2023-11-06T14:38:22.668+02:00 DEBUG 7100 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .s.o.c.w.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [f865bdf4-8438-4ac5-a587-917ed06fb82e], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=hdODzgXtXVwmIIC8I0_-Lg, sub=f865bdf4-8438-4ac5-a587-917ed06fb82e, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/realms/john, typ=ID, preferred_username=john, given_name=, nonce=BoS9yhBYY4d-aY0yHdbX-3IK_LF6uBl3uFEQ1vp6L6c, sid=06bb0831-88be-4580-8717-e08985098f2c, aud=[john-rest-api], acr=1, azp=john-rest-api, auth_time=2023-11-06T12:38:22Z, exp=2023-11-06T12:43:22Z, session_state=06bb0831-88be-4580-8717-e08985098f2c, family_name=, iat=2023-11-06T12:38:22Z, jti=3951b6f2-fda1-4374-8e81-556881d7c9a6}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=F4F280CA99D66DCFD5C20757B8D61BEA], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]
2023-11-06T14:38:22.669+02:00 DEBUG 7100 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/api/v1/demo/hello-2?continue
2023-11-06T14:38:22.699+02:00 DEBUG 7100 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/v1/demo/hello-2?continue
2023-11-06T14:38:22.700+02:00 DEBUG 7100 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Loaded matching saved request http://localhost:8080/api/v1/demo/hello-2?continue
2023-11-06T14:38:22.702+02:00 DEBUG 7100 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [f865bdf4-8438-4ac5-a587-917ed06fb82e], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=hdODzgXtXVwmIIC8I0_-Lg, sub=f865bdf4-8438-4ac5-a587-917ed06fb82e, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:8180/realms/john, typ=ID, preferred_username=john, given_name=, nonce=BoS9yhBYY4d-aY0yHdbX-3IK_LF6uBl3uFEQ1vp6L6c, sid=06bb0831-88be-4580-8717-e08985098f2c, aud=[john-rest-api], acr=1, azp=john-rest-api, auth_time=2023-11-06T12:38:22Z, exp=2023-11-06T12:43:22Z, session_state=06bb0831-88be-4580-8717-e08985098f2c, family_name=, iat=2023-11-06T12:38:22Z, jti=3951b6f2-fda1-4374-8e81-556881d7c9a6}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=F4F280CA99D66DCFD5C20757B8D61BEA], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]]
2023-11-06T14:38:22.702+02:00 DEBUG 7100 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /api/v1/demo/hello-2?continue
2023-11-06T14:38:22.704+02:00 DEBUG 7100 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] horizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor : Authorizing method invocation ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public java.util.Map com.example.keycloak.DemoController.hello2(); target is of class [com.example.keycloak.DemoController]
2023-11-06T14:38:22.705+02:00 DEBUG 7100 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] horizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor : Failed to authorize ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public java.util.Map com.example.keycloak.DemoController.hello2(); target is of class [com.example.keycloak.DemoController] with authorization manager org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.DeferringObservationAuthorizationManager@53e70692 and decision ExpressionAuthorizationDecision [granted=false, expressionAttribute=hasRole('client_admin')]
```

Comment: I edited post with the logs . As long I understand, my spring boot application needs to access the resource , so it is the client and I registered it on Keycloak to act as a client in this oauth2 flow,  Keycloak acts as authorization server, and resource server I imagine is again by spring boot app, since it holds the resource . Correct me if I understand something wrong

Comment: You can't acess all resources directly because they are secured and must be accessed with access tokens generated by authorization provider (in this case Keycloak). In logs , the role I want is not part of Granted Authorities because my converter is never accessed, if it was , the role would be added in Granted Authorities

Comment: Check my previous comment please:  the role I want is not part of Granted Authorities because my converter is never accessed, if it was , the role would be added in Granted Authorities. In converter() method of JwtAuthConverter (my custom one) , this is what I do, i take the roles and add them to Grant Authorities , the problem is that this method is never accessed. Also, after oauth2Login you can access the resources because you get an authorization code and an access code, so you don't access them directly, but through an access code.

Comment: You didn't show your code, so nobody could say, why it is not working ::  I say that the method is never accessed, so whatever I do in this method, right or wrong has no impact.  A role should not added in converter, it should be configured in Keycloak : of course it is confiured in Keycloak, I configured that the user I log in with, to have the specific role I check, but then you need to add it to the Grant Authorities, because only these :OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile , are added by default. Do you have any solution on why the converter is never called?

Comment: we have no idea what your request looks like, since you have not posted it, so how should we know why it isnt called?

Comment: What do you mean "what the request looks like"? It's just a simple get method through browser that's trying to access the resource  "api/hello-2"

Comment: "It's just a simple get method through browser!" How can we know? you havnt included it in your question! im sorry but we are not mind readers, enable trace debugging and update your question with the trace logs.

Comment: _Request with browser (not postman) means get_ no it doesnt a browser does OPTION, GET, POST, HEAD, PUT and many other types of requests. The only person here that is rude is you and you are the one that is asking for help. We have no obligation to help you. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Authorities mapping is not done the same for OAuth2 client with login and for OAuth2 resource server.

Using a `Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken>` (like `JwtAuthenticationConverter`) is adapted only to OAuth2 resource servers with JWT decoder (but neither to OAuth2 resource servers with introspection nor OAuth2 clients with `oauth2Login`).

For [OAuth2 clients with `oauth2Login`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities), this is done with either a `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` or an `OAuth2UserService` (the first is simpler and enough in most cases).

As a side note, you should not mix `oauth2Login` and `resourceServer` in the same security filter-chain. Configuration requirements are too different (security is based on sessions for clients with login, which makes CSRF protection necessary, when security is based on tokens for resource servers which makes sessions and CSRF protection unnecessary).

As you are using `oauth2Login`, my guess is that you are actually not using tokens (check in your browser debugging tools, you'll find session cookie but not any `Authorization` header containing a `Bearer` token). The `resourceServer` configuration only makes sense if you have an OAuth2 client sending requests with an access token. Browsers can't be OAuth2 client by themselves. It need a Javascript framework configured for that, and it need this framework to be configured as *public* OAuth2 client, [which is now discouraged](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390).

If your UI is a Spring application with Thymeleaf (or any other server-side rendering framework), two options:

- if the MVC controllers use a REST client (`WebClient`, `RestClient`, `RestTemplate`, `@FeignClient`, etc.) to make internal REST calls to an API exposed to other OAuth2 clients, then separate security in two distinct `SecurityFilterChain` beans: one for OAuth2 client with login (MVC controller endpoints rendering templates) and another with OAuth2 resource server config for REST API. I wrote a [tutorial for that](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui)
- if the REST API is not exposed publicly (only consumed by your UI using sessions), just remove the `resourceServer` configuration, along with your `JwtAuthenticationConverter`.

If your UI is a SPA, then two options too:

- remove the `resourceServer` configuration from your REST API (use it solely as an OAuth2 client with login and sessions), but this is not ideal for scalability and fault tolerance
- remove `oauth2Login` (keep the REST API solely as a stateless resource server) and insert a Backend For Frontend between your frontend and this API. I created a [BFF tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff) using `spring-cloud-gateway` as OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login` and the `TokenRelay` filter.

Answer (score -3):

Is the above code complete? I see `private final JwtAuthConverter jwtAuthConverter;` but no code giving it it's initial value.

---

An alternative approach would be to create a Bean of type `org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationConverter` and customize it:

```
@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationConverter oauth2JwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(new CustomJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter());
    return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
}
```

where `CustomJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter` is a custom class which handles the granted authorities, ROLE_ etc

Comment: *but no code giving it it's initial value*  It is injected by Spring.

Comment: *An alternative approach would be to create a Bean* OP already created a bean with `@Component`.

Comment: my own JwtAuthConverter  is injected by Spring with constructor injection. Tried the above but the result is the same

Comment: He is using `oauth2Login` with his browser => requests are authorized with sessions (not JWTs) => JWT authentication converter won't be called. Use `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` or `OAuth2UserService` to map authorities in OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login`.